# How to make C++ function to return a vector of all the permutations of char array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I don't have much experience with C++ programming and what I would like to do is the following:

1) Make a function which takes a char array as input (e.g. 'abb')

2) The function will calculate all the premutations of the char array and store them in a vector

3) The function will return this vector of char arrays

Can anyone give me a quick example how this could be done in C++? I googled but I couldn't find what I was looking for exactly :P

So for example the input would be 'abb' and the function would return a vector containing char arrays: 'abb', 'bab' and 'bba'

Comment: C++ has a function to make permutations, you can use it.

Comment: C++ have some very nice [algorithms in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). I'm sure you might be able to find [something suitable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> p(std::vector<char> v)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> result;

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    do
    {
        result.push_back(v);  // result.emplace_back(v);
    }
    while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

    return result;
}
```

To use:

```
auto v = p({'a','b','c'});

for (auto &c : v)
{
    for (auto &x : c)
        cout << x;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Comment: By the way, when I try to run the code above I get the error message: "error: 'class std::vector<std::vector<char> >' has no member named 'emplace_back'". Any idea of the cause? Has it got something to do with my compiler? which is GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: @jjepsuomi: Replace `emplace_back` by `push_back`. You should enable C++11 by `-std=c++11` switch to go into new C++ world.